# puppet exec: could not find command 'source'

Tags: exec, puppet

```
 exec {'alias':
   command  => 'source /etc/profile',
   path =>  [ '/bin/', '/sbin/' , '/usr/bin/', '/usr/sbin/' ],
   provider => shell,
 }
```

### /etc/profile

```
alias extend_shutdown_15='bash extend_shutdown.sh 15'
```

So here I want to update the "/etc/profile" after any configuration changes on same while using "source /etc/profile" command in exec resource, but I get these errors:

```
Error: Could not find command 'source'
Error: /Stage[main]/Main/Node[default]/Exec[alias]/returns: change from 'notrun' to ['0'] failed: Could not find command 'source' (corrective)
```

Comment: `source /etc/profile` will not cause any permanent changes even if it succeeds. Why do you want to do this?

Comment: I want  to create aliases for commands so i'm planning to add into /etc/profile to make global ,so effect these configuration changes  into our system need to run "reboot" or "source /etc/profile" ? and i'm trying these puppet exec but getting  error due to source command

Comment: Ok then an isolated `source /etc/profile` in an `exec` resource will not achieve this for you. You should probably look at doing this some other way.

Comment: Moreover, putting aliases into `/etc/profile` does not make them global anyway.  Depending on the circumstances and arguments, that file is not always read during shell initialization.  Also, aliases are not passed on to child processes, and by default, they are not expanded by non-interactive shells.  Plus, they are not shared with people who use alternative shells.  If you want to add new commands to the system then consider writing executable shell scripts and putting them somewhere in the default PATH.

Answer (score 0):

This ...

> ```
> Error: Could not find command 'source'
> ```

... relates to the `command` parameter of your `Exec`, not to the specific contents of file `/etc/profile`.  The problem is exactly what the error message says: `source` is not a known command.

Perhaps you are used to a shell from the Csh family, which offers `source` as a builtin, but Puppet will instead invoke a POSIX shell.  Or perhaps you are used to Bash, Zsh, or Ksh providing `source` as a built-in command, but that is an extension.  The POSIX shell language does not define a `source` builtin, and it is not a standard utility.  Bash, at least, will not recognize `source` when it runs in POSIX mode, and that's the way I would expect Puppet to invoke it (or whatever the default shell is on your system).

The equivalent command in the POSIX shell language is `.` (a single period / full-stop character).  I would expect, then, that this `Exec` would be applied without error:

```
 exec { 'alias':
   command  => '. /etc/profile',
   path     => [ '/bin', '/sbin' , '/usr/bin', '/usr/sbin' ],
   provider => 'shell',
 }
```

As described in comments, however, that's largely useless.  It will not affect the environment or aliases of anything that runs outside the scope of that `Exec` (it *can't*). Moreover, aliases are a questionable way to proceed, anyway.

Having written that, I now realize that this is probably an XY question.  I suggest posting a new question that focuses on the thing you are trying to do instead of on this particular idea for how to do it.